# regex not continuing

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse some bbc code like this:

```
[item=1]a[/item]
[item=2]b[/item]
[item=3]c[/item]
```

I'm able to get the first item, but i can't get the second and third. I'm trying to grab each item, and convert it to a link. Here's the result i'm going for:

```
<a href="#1">a</a>
<a href="#2">b</a>
<a href="#3">c</a>
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
/\[item=(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/item\]/
```

Which gives me:

```
["[item=1]a[/item]", "1", "a"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong depends on the language you are using, and you don't tell us that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the "global" option to your expression

```
/\[item=(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/item\]/gi
```

That **should** work on most regex implementations, but when your provide which one you are using (or at least what language you are programming in), I can check into that.

On a further note: Add the case-insensitive option also, so `ITEM` will also be matched.

On a further futher note: Here is a [working example](http://regexr.com?3010t)

Comment: I wish I could +1 this a million times, not only for that wonderful answer, but that AMAZING program you included!

Comment: Happy to help - but for further questions, please be sure to always include the _programming language_ you are using and also some example code on _how_ you are currently doing things!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I figured it the language didn't matter since regex is regex right?

Comment: It would be nice if that were true... But, as with mostly everything in programming, there are many flavors and tiny differences in implementations. As for regex, just check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Language_features) to see what I mean ;-)